# Fastest protocol for mounting a NAS for Linux and Mac

Tags: raid, nas, samba, nfs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Samba vs. NFS: Performance](https://superuser.com/questions/18729/samba-vs-nfs-performance)
>   [AFP, SMB, NFS which is the best data transfer protocol ?](https://superuser.com/questions/106418/afp-smb-nfs-which-is-the-best-data-transfer-protocol)

I am building a file server with RAID 10.

I need a way to access the files from multiple machines, both Linux and Mac machines.
I could always go with Samba, but I'm wondering if there is a faster/more efficient protocol for getting the most from the RAID system.

Would NFS be a better option? Or am I just being pedantic?

Comment: and: [AFP, SMB, NFS which is the best data transfer protocol?](http://superuser.com/questions/106418/afp-smb-nfs-which-is-the-best-data-transfer-protocol)